# C++ HashTable issue with find function

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am trying to code here HashTable. I have pretty much coded all of the function and the program is compiling with the main. but my find function for some reason it's taking forever to run with the main I have. Also,  when test for copy constructor and operator= the program is crashing. below is the hashtable

```
structure 
{
    struct Record
    {
        TYPE data_;
        string key_;
        Record* Next ;

        Record(const string& key, const TYPE& data)
        {
            key_ = key;
            data_ = data;
        }
        Record()
        {
            key_  = "" ;
            Next = nullptr;
        }



    };
    int TableSize ;
    Record** records ;


    template <class TYPE>
    bool HashTable<TYPE>::find(const string& key, TYPE& value)
    {
        // int index = std::hash<TYPE> {}(value)%TableSize ;
        int index = std::hash<string> {}(key)%TableSize ;
        Record* temp = records[index] ;
        while(temp != nullptr )
        {
            if(temp->data_ == value && temp->key_ == key)
                return true ;
            temp = temp->Next ;
        }
        return false ;
    }

operator= 

    template <class TYPE>
    const HashTable<TYPE>& HashTable<TYPE>::operator=(const HashTable<TYPE>& other)
    {
        if(this != &other)
        {
            if(records)
            {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < TableSize; i++)
                    remove(records[i]->key_);
                delete[] records ;
            }
            records = new Record*[other.TableSize] ;
            TableSize = other.TableSize ;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < other.TableSize ; i++)
            {
                update(records[i]->key_, records[i]->data_);

            }

        }

        return *this;

    }

    template <class TYPE>
    HashTable<TYPE>::HashTable(const HashTable<TYPE>& other)
    {
        if(other.records != nullptr)
        {
            if(records)
            {

                delete[] records ;
                cout<<"delete"<<endl;

            }

            records = new Record*[other.TableSize];



            TableSize = other.TableSize;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < other.TableSize; i++)
                records[i] = new Record();

            for (int i = 0; i<other.TableSize; i++)
            {
                update(other.records[i]->key_, other.records[i]->data_);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            records = nullptr;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashTable<TYPE>::HashTable(const HashTable<TYPE>& other)
{
    // ...
        if (records) {
            delete[] records ;
```

There is no situation in which it is ok to do this.

You're constructing a new object, and you haven't initialized any of its members yet (which is bad practise in itself). Using the value of something it was your responsibility to initialize is already bad, but deleting whatever junk happened to be in there is likely to be disastrous.

It does make sense in your `operator=`, because there the object already exists.